# SMA antenna extension

Tags: antenna

My GSM module is in such a place that antenna should be at least 100ft away from it to get signal(2g.) I searched for SMA coaxial antenna extension cables but they are only available in 25ft.

Is there a limit such that this long extension will degrade the network quality?

If I connect regular 100ft wire to helical antenna, will it work?

Comment: The coaxial cable itself also has loss. 
If you just connect regular wire, it will not work, you really need proper coaxial cables.

Comment: This will not work well by any practical means
  You should move the module to the antenna location and run the data connections back.   Also note 2g is being phased out.

Comment: @ChrisStratton then is it possible to communicate between arduino and gsm module through 100ft of wire?

Comment: Of course, if you do it right.  It is not trivial, but eaasier than extending the antenna which would degrade performance even when done right.  Again though 2g is obsolete and an Arduino based project sounds like it might not be robust enough to be worth the expense and effort of such an install.